# Reduce an array to a specific structure using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of the objects

```
[
    {"id":"brand","label":"Brand","value":"value1"},    
    {"id":"waterproof","label":"Waterproof","value":"value1"},
    {"id":"diameter","label":"Diameter","value":""},
    {"id":"brand","label":"Brand","value":"value2"},
    {"id":"waterproof","label":"Waterproof","value":"value2"},
    {"id":"diameter","label":"Diameter","value":""}
]
```

I need to restructure it to a following structure,

```
[
    ["Brand", "value1", "value2"], 
    ["Waterproof", "value1","value2"], 
    ["Diameter","",""]
]
```

Any ideas on how I could do this using a reduce method.

Best

Comment: specify how you got from input to output

Comment: where do you get `value2` from?

Comment: @NinaScholz `    {"id":"brand","label":"Brand","value":"value2"},`

Answer (score 2):

Yust take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and collect all values.

```js
var json = '[{"id":"brand","label":"Brand","value":"value1"},{"id":"waterproof","label":"Waterproof","value":"value1"},{"id":"diameter","label":"Diameter","value":""},{"id":"brand","label":"Brand","value":"value2"},{"id":"waterproof","label":"Waterproof","value":"value2"},{"id":"diameter","label":"Diameter","value":""}]',
    result = Array.from(JSON
        .parse(json)
        .reduce((m, { id, label, value }) => m.set(id, (m.get(id) || [label]).concat(value)), new Map)
        .values()
    );
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: It is not the expected result

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal, right. now it should return the expected result.

Answer (score 2):

Try following using [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

```js
let arr = [{"id":"brand","label":"Brand","value":"value1"},{"id":"waterproof","label":"Waterproof","value":"value1"},{"id":"diameter","label":"Diameter","value":""},{"id":"brand","label":"Brand","value":"value2"},{"id":"waterproof","label":"Waterproof","value":"value2"},{"id":"diameter","label":"Diameter","value":""}];

let result = Object.values(arr.reduce((a,c) => {
  if(a[c.id]) a[c.id].push(c.value);
  else a[c.id] = [c.label, c.value];
  return a;
}, {}));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: @BobanStanojevic - Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Not the best of code but i think this might be useful for you:

```
let data = [
        {"id":"brand","label":"Brand","value":"value1"},    
        {"id":"waterproof","label":"Waterproof","value":"value1"},
        {"id":"diameter","label":"Diameter","value":""},
        {"id":"brand","label":"Brand","value":"value2"},
        {"id":"waterproof","label":"Waterproof","value":"value2"},
        {"id":"diameter","label":"Diameter","value":""}
    ]

    let reducedData = {}
    data.forEach((row)=>{
        reducedData[row.id] ? reducedData[row.id].push(row.value) : reducedData[row.id] = [row.label, row.value]    
    })
    let newData = Object.keys(reducedData).map((id)=>{return [...reducedData[id]]})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a simple combo of  [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and  [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```js
const data = [{"id":"brand","label":"Brand","value":"value1"},{"id":"waterproof","label":"Waterproof","value":"value1"},{"id":"diameter","label":"Diameter","value":""},{"id":"brand","label":"Brand","value":"value2"},{"id":"waterproof","label":"Waterproof","value":"value2"},{"id":"diameter","label":"Diameter","value":""}];

const grouped = data.reduce((o, { label, value }) =>
    ({...o, [label]: [...(o[label] || []), value]}), {});

const result = Object.keys(grouped).map(label => [label, ...grouped[label]]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I use Set to create a unique list of `id`'s then I `map` to create a custom array based on those `id`'s. This is done by using find to get the label, and filter to get all the items that are related to the `id`. I map again on the filter to just return the `value` of the object.

```js
let items = [
    {"id":"brand","label":"Brand","value":"value1"},    
    {"id":"waterproof","label":"Waterproof","value":"value1"},
    {"id":"diameter","label":"Diameter","value":""},
    {"id":"brand","label":"Brand","value":"value2"},
    {"id":"waterproof","label":"Waterproof","value":"value2"},
    {"id":"diameter","label":"Diameter","value":""}
]

let result = [...new Set(items.map(i => i.id))]
  .map(id => {
    return [
      items.find(i => i.id == id).label,
      ...items.filter(i => i.id == id).map(i => i.value)
    ]
  })

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case the JSON Array is a very long one from some API

```
var data = [
    {"id":"brand","label":"Brand","value":"value1"},    
    {"id":"waterproof","label":"Waterproof","value":"value1"},
    ...... //some JSON array form some API
];
var json = JSON.stringify(data);

result = Array.from(JSON
    .parse(json)
    .reduce((m, { id, label, value }) => m.set(id, (m.get(id) || [label]).concat(value)), new Map)
    .values()
);
console.log(result);
```